# Problems when reading a JSON

Tags: java, json, apache-commons

I am trying to read a JSON from the internal network of my company, I have configured

```
  System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
or
  System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "XX.XX.XX.XX");
  System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "XXXX");
```

I can read the API publicly without problems on the internet

But when reading my company's API instead of a JSON it returns an HTML table

```
json = (java.lang.String) "<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>status</th><th>message_code</th><th>devices</th><th>message</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>SUCCESS</td><td>Array</td><td>Success</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have used

```
String json = IOUtils.toString(url, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

and

```
  URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
```

**I solved the problem using this code**

```
URL url = new URL(sURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));
```

Comment: Can you get the json when calling through Postman?

Comment: yes I used RESTClient on Firefox